# How to include a file, inside subdirectory in Codeigniter 4 Views

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-4

I want include a file. I know I can include a file if the file is in same directory, for example

```
.
├── about.php
├── admin
│   ├── customer.php
│   ├── detailorder.php
│   ├── footer.php
│   ├── header.php
│   ├── index.php
│   ├── inventory.php
│   ├── laporan
│   │   ├── inventory.php
│   │   ├── omset.php
│   │   ├── pembatalan.php
│   │   ├── penjualan.php
│   │   ├── produksi.php
│   │   └── profit.php
│   ├── login.php
├── checkout.php
├── detail_produk.php
├── footer.php
├── header.php
├── index.php
└── welcome_message.php
```

tree directory above is in Views folder of CI4 project. I can include the `header.php` file from `index.php` file also i can include `header.php` file from `admin/customer.php` that because `header.php` file is in the same directory as the file want to include.

But, how to include `header.php` file in `admin/header.php` to file in `admin/laporan/inventory.php`

I have tried `../header.php` and `../admin/header.php` but it didn't work

Comment: Provide code with `include`, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the full path based on the `Views` folder, like so:

```php
<?= $this->include('admin/header.php') ?>
```